# Как словить событие закрытие и открытие крышки ноутбука в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, события, обновление, javascript-events

Мне нужно реализовать автообновление страницы после выхода ПК из сна, а также после разблокировки экрана. Уже целый день сижу над этим таском и не могу решить.

Comment: Скорее всего никак, вычисляйте по косвенным признакам

Comment: А я на `js` недавно написал скрипт который ворота в гараж открывает:D приблизительно такой же сложности. А если серьёзно вам нужно отследить когда пользователь ушёл из вкладки и когда вернулся. Такой вопрос уже был я помню.

Comment: window.addEventListener('blur'
window.addEventListener('focus'
помогут думаю

Comment: Ну тогда никак:) такого события точно уж нет)

Answer (score 7):

Нет такого события)))
Как вариант используйте события `window.onoffline` и `window.ononline` Тем самым вы можете определить состояние Интернет соединения.

```js
var sts = document.getElementById('status'),
  eventStatus = function(e){
   console.log(e.type);
   sts.className = e.type;
  };
window.onoffline = window.ononline = eventStatus;
sts.className = navigator.onLine ? 'online' : 'offline';
```

```css
#status {
 display: block;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 border-radius: 50%;
}
#status.online {
 background-color: green;
}
#status.offline {
 background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="status"></div>
```

Comment: Воу, таких событий нет.. Но за  мысли в верную сторону `+`

Comment: Есть такие события. Chrome, Opera, Mozilla, IE11 точно есть.

Comment: Я прогуглил только что, это события которые пишешь сам:)  Зависят от `navigator.onLine` так что событий таких  нет, но мысли хорошие.

Comment: @Zicrael мною было разработано расширение "Онлайн радио в твоём браузере" и одним из функционалов было продолжение приема стрима при обрыве соединения. Я знаю о чём пишу.https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/ononline Вы бы по-тестили...)))

Comment: Это хорошо:) ну значит такое есть , только в ответе измените на `window` на `document`

Comment: @Zicrael В консоли попробуйте и будете удивлены. У меня всё верно.

Answer (score 2):

Еще есть событие `visibilitychange`, в отличие от `focus/blur`, генерируется только в случаях, если пользователь переключил вкладку либо минимизировал браузер. Сработает ли при закрытии крышки ноута - проверить возможности нет. Проверьте - расскажите нам.

```js
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", chekVisibility);
function chekVisibility(event){
console.log(event);
console.log(document.hidden)
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]